# Can the Meta sites have non-color-based visual cues to help distinguish them from the Main sites?

Tags: feature-request, design, per-site-meta

A color-blind user posted a [feature-request](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/could-the-meta-site-be-more-clearly-labeled) on our English.SE site, asking for non-color-based visual cues to help distinguish the Meta site from the Main site.

I think it is an excellent request to accommodate users with poor color vision.  Some of the suggestions on that user's request included

- Making the "meta" more prominent in the title
- Changing the question/answer separators
- Changing the border around the question title

We haven't heard anything back about this feature request on our site, but it seems this would be helpful on the other SE sites as well.

And Robert Harvey, yes, actually, it would be helpful if ours *were* prominent, like on this site.  Ours looks like this:
[image: Meta site header]

which is pretty identical to the main:
[image: Main site header]

except for the coloration and a weensy "meta" that can be easily overlooked if you can't see reds well. This is how the headers look to a red-green color-blind person, courtesy of http://colorfilter.wickline.org/ :

[image: meta (protan)]

[image: main (protan)]

And this is how they look in greyscale:

[image: meta (greyscale)]

[image: main (greyscale)]

Making it blink would be unnecessary.

Programmers, TeX, and Apple also have very similar Main and Meta banners, for instance (I think the TeX sites are particularly difficult to distinguish).

Comment: You mean like the `meta` over the logo above?  Maybe we could make it blink.

Comment: @RobertHarvey On some sites, the “meta” bit in the logo is in comparatively small type, and less contrasted (I don't know how it looks to a color-blind user).

Comment: Maybe something http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/vischeckURL.php would be useful? Though this site doesn't process images.

Comment: That other question should have been tagged with "design", a tag Jin frequents and actively checks as far as I know.

Comment: Also, beta sites use text, not graphics, for titles; there is only a single-letter difference between "Foo Beta" and "Foo Meta".  I have to use CSS overrides for font colors and there's no way for me to color those differently (they're both links).  This trips me up *all the time*.  I realize it's a pretty special case, but if the fix for the color-blindness problem could also address my problem I'd be thrilled.  For example (not necessarily the best approach), if the "meta" were either larger or smaller than the "beta" on the main site, that'd be a big clue.

Comment: @ChrisF http://colorfilter.wickline.org/ (supports images)

Comment: @YannisRizos idk what that is, but it is **blocked** at my office.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA [Blame Jeff Zeldman, not me](http://www.zeldman.com/2007/10/10/testing-designs-for-color-blindness/). Anyway I don't see anything wrong with the site, a false positive perhaps?

Comment: @YannisRizos possibly.

Comment: Arqade doesn't even say "meta"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some sites (like Stack Overflow and Server Fault) have ***GREAT BIG [META]s*** in their Meta logos.

Other sites like English have <sup><sub>puny little [META]s</sub></sup>.

I support [META] equality!

If elected I will impose a [META] tax on wealthier sites to help subsidize small family.... er - sorry, slipped into election mode there.